Unity 2D Platformer that saves your past positions and replays them as a "Ghost"
I have been trying to get better at C# and Unity. As my first programming language and game engine, there are still a lot of things I do not yet understand. I know the basics of both, but I don't know how to use the knowledge I have to create things. I know the basics of C# syntax, the 4 pillars of OOP, SOLID and Design patterns. But I don't know how to use that knowledge together to create the games that I see online. That's why I have been trying to learn about design patterns, in hopes of getting better at problem solving, structuring, C# and Unity overall.
I tried my hands on using "The Command Pattern" to make a replay system(kind of) in Unity. When you go through portals that take you to another part of the map, you will see another you go the path that you previously went on.
I made a quick little game like that, but I don't know how to structure it, and I am not sure I used the command pattern in the right way.
Basically this is how the code is connected:


dash means field
arrow is implements(Except the input)


PlayerInput
public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
 {
  public static PlayerInput Instance;

private void Awake()
{
    if(Instance == null)
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}


private float _hor;
private Vector2 _moveDir;

void Update()
{
    _hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    _moveDir = new Vector2(_hor, transform.position.y);
}
public Vector2 GetInput()
{
    return _moveDir;
}
}


Shadow
public class Shadow : MonoBehaviour
{
private CommandManager _commandManager = null;
public void SetCommandMananager(CommandManager commandManager)
{
    _commandManager = commandManager;
}
private bool _canShadow = true;
public Coroutine _currentCoroutine;
public void StartPosition(Vector3 position)
{
    transform.position = position;
}

public void Update()
{
    if(_commandManager != null && _canShadow)
    {
        _canShadow = false;
        _currentCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ShadowRoutine());
        Debug.Log("Starting");
    }
}
private IEnumerator ShadowRoutine()
{
    while (_commandManager.CommandStack.Count > 0)
    {
        var pos = _commandManager.RemoveCommand().Undo();
        transform.position += new Vector3(pos.x, 0, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
    _canShadow = true;
    _commandManager = null;
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
    Debug.Log("Not Starting");
}
public void HaveRoutine()
{
    if(_currentCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(_currentCoroutine);
    }
    _currentCoroutine = null;
    _canShadow = true;
}
}


Portal
public class Portal : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private PlayerController _playerController;
[SerializeField] private Shadow _shadow;
[SerializeField] private Transform _transformPosition;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out PlayerController playerController))
    {
        _shadow.HaveRoutine();
        _shadow.StartPosition(_playerController.StartPos);
        _shadow.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _shadow.SetCommandMananager(playerController.CommandManager);

        playerController.CommandManager = new CommandManager();
        _playerController.transform.position = _transformPosition.position;
        _playerController.StartPos = _transformPosition.position;
    }
}
}


CommandManager
public class CommandManager
{
private Queue<ICommand> _commandStack = new Queue<ICommand>();
public Queue<ICommand> CommandStack => _commandStack;
public void AddCommand(ICommand newCommand)
{
    _commandStack.Enqueue(newCommand);
}
public ICommand RemoveCommand()
{
    if(_commandStack.Count > 0)
    {
        return _commandStack.Dequeue();
    }
    return null;
}
}


MoveCommand
public class MoveCommand : ICommand
{
private Vector2 _translation;

public MoveCommand(Vector2 translation)
{
    _translation = translation;
}

public Vector2 Execute()
{
    return _translation;
}
public Vector2 Undo()
{
    return _translation;
}
}


ICommand
public interface ICommand
{
Vector2 Execute();
Vector2 Undo();
}


PlayerController
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
private MoveCommand _moveCommand;
private CommandManager _commandManager = new CommandManager();
public CommandManager CommandManager
{
    get => _commandManager;
    set => _commandManager = value;
}
private float _speed = 5f;
public Vector3 StartPos { get; set; }
private void Awake()
{
    StartPos = transform.position;
}

public void Update()
{
    if(PlayerInput.Instance.GetInput().magnitude != 0)
    {
        _moveCommand = new MoveCommand(PlayerInput.Instance.GetInput() * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += new Vector3(_moveCommand.Execute().x, 0, 0);
        _commandManager.AddCommand(_moveCommand);
    }
}
}

How can I improve the code, the structure, the logic and am I using the command pattern right? I know that you are supposed to execute the logic on the commandObject, but I couldn't come up with anything that would work. I saved the transform on the MoveCommand class before, but that made it tied to a specific object, the object which provided the transform, which didn't make it work with the ghost.

Rather than having an annotated relationship diagram I would suggest to create a sequence diagram. That could reveal some potential leaky abstractions or unwanted interactions.
